# Как фильтровать соотвествующий элемент из массива

Tags: массивы, kotlin

**У меня есть массив строк, из которого я хочу удалить соответствующий элемент. Есть ли встроенная функция?**

```
 val myArray = arrayOf("repair","consist","several")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете получить копию массива без некоторого элемента вызовом функции:

```
val myArray = arrayOf("repair", "consist", "several")
val filteredArray = myArray.filterNot { it == "repair" } // repair здесь как пример
```

Либо же Вы можете использовать изменяемую версию (но уже не массива, а списка):

```
val myList = mutableListOf("repair", "consist", "several")
myList.remove("repair")
```

У этих методов есть варианты:

`removeAt` - Удаляет по индексу из изменяемого списка

`filter` - Оставляет только элементы, подходящие под условие

`filterIndexed` - Как `filter`, только в условии можно использовать индекс

Comment: Ок спасибо !!!!!